# I am having a tableview with multiple cell in it and in each cell having tableview, collectionview, tableview, like that

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

How to handle **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** so that it works on all the three different cell for each cell in it?

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRQ3Z.png)

[Flow of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwwei.png)

```html
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([[dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqual:@"Traffic" ])
        {
            if(!TrafficCell)
            {
                TrafficCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CollectionVIewTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                NSDictionary *dict=dataArray[indexPath.row];
                TrafficCell.Traffic = [dict valueForKey:@"detail"];
                [TrafficCell.collectionView reloadData];
                return TrafficCell;
            }
            return TrafficCell;
        }
    else if([[dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqual:@"News"])
    {
        if(!NewsCell)
        {
            NewsTableViewCell *cell = (NewsTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSDictionary *dict=dataArray[indexPath.row];
            cell.News = [dict valueForKey:@"detail"];
            [cell.NewsTableView reloadData];
            return cell;
        }
        return NewsCell;
        
    }
    
        else
        {
            if(!CategoryCell)
            {
        CategoryCell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CategoryTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                NSDictionary *dict=dataArray[indexPath.row];
                CategoryCell.Category = [dict valueForKey:@"detail"];
                [CategoryCell.CategorycollectionView reloadData];
                return CategoryCell;
            }
            return CategoryCell;
        }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


}
```

Comment: Please explain with more details ?

Comment: In the pic which i have uploaded the data are showing like olx, Naukri.com, they are in collection view and data like Rice in all goodness are in tableview i want them to pass them to the webview.

Comment: Do not implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath for your main tableView. Instead, create delegates for TrafficCell, NewsCell, CategoryCell and handle their functionality accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle tap on `UITableViewCell` the same as you implement in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
           NSDictionary *dict = dataArray[indexPath.row];
           UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
           if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"Traffic" ]){
              //Find your collectionView in cell
              //Tap on Traffic cells
           }
           else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"News"]){
              //Tap on News cells 
           }
           else {
                //Tap on other cells
           }
    }
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need

```
TrafficCell.collectionView.delegate = self;
CategoryCell.CategorycollectionView.delegate = self;
```

for handle tap on `UICollectionViewCell` and implement `UICollectionViewDelegate` method

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //Tapped on your collectionViewCell inside the uitableviewcell
}
```

Comment: Thanks @iShashok for this Answer.